# move cursor in contentEditable mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, contenteditable

I have a problem with contentEditable, at least in chrome divs and spans are added as the user edits the text content in the DIVs.

Once the DIV is opened for edit, I can move my cursor around by single-clicking (left mousebutton) but if the text I want to move the cursor to resides within one of the sub-divs or sub-spans added by chrome, the cursor is not moved but instead taken out of the div all together, and I have to activate the contenteditable again.

Is there a way around this or can I do nothing about it?

Comment: Here is my answer to this issue.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547209/jquery-remove-span-tags-while-preserving-their-contents-and-replace-divs-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

[jquery remove <span> tags while preserving their contents (and replace <divs> and <p>:s with <br>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547209/jquery-remove-span-tags-while-preserving-their-contents-and-replace-divs-an)

in short, pull out all text from divs and p tags, substitute their opening tags with a br, and for those span tags that keep appearing upon backspace (in chrome), I just unwrap them. That gets rid of the style automatically.